# Limit on alcohol bottles or containers when traveling back into the US

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, alcohol

Is there currently a limit or maximum allowance of declared number or measurement of alcohol (whether wine, liquor, beer) bottles/containers when traveling into the United States for American Citizens?

This question arose as I recently returned from a (Jamaican) cruise (from the Port of New Orleans) and brought back four 1 liter bottles of rum.

Or does this differ from state to state as well? As alcohol regulation is a deferred state right?

Comment: I'm removing the tsa tag since this seems to have nothing to do with the TSA.  If I've missed something, please advise.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can bring back as many as you want, however, you will only get the first liter free from duties.  "The other will be dutiable at 3 percent, plus any Internal Revenue Service tax."

Source: [U.S. Customs and Border Protection](http://www.cbp.gov/xp/cgov/travel/vacation/kbyg/paying_duty.xml).

Comment: This might be a stupid question, but do I show them the receipt so that they can calculate 3% of what I paid for the wine?

Comment: You don't need the receipt, but it's a good idea to have it.  Normally they accept the value that you have declared on your customs forms. But if that price is unusually low (you bought your rum very cheaply), they may ask to see the receipt. If you don't have it, they will assign a price based on the usual sale price for similar goods.